# Can't figure out what is wrong with the code. Trying an alternative for string.find()

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

When I try to print the variables indA, indB or string it seems to work. Two letters and a word are inputted, and if the letters are present in the word, the characters between the two letters are printed.

```
def substring_between_letters(word, start, end):
  for index in range(len(word)):

    if word[index] == start:
      indA = index
      break
      return indA

    if word[index] == end:
      indB = index
      break
      return indB
      string = word[indA + 1 : indB]

    else:
      string = word

  return string
```

Comment: the code after the breaks will never get called as a break immediately terminates the for loop

Comment: add some explanation with an example what your code is doing

Comment: Thanks for asking a question here. Please change your title to something that is in question format, more than 'what is wrong here'. Check out how to ask great questions right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def substring_between_letters(word, start, end):
    hasA = False # Checks if start has already been found
    for index in range(len(word)):
        if word[index] == start:
            hasA = True
            aIndex = index
        if hasA and word[index] == end:
            bIndex = index
            return word[aIndex: bIndex + 1]
    return word # If substring could not be found
```

For instance:

```
>>> print(substring_between_letters("hello everyone!", "l", "e"))
lo e
```

The problems with your code include:

- The `break` statements cause exiting of the loop before `string` can be defined. A better way to write this function actually forgoes `break` statements.
- Returning the indA and indB causes the output of the function to just be a single integer.
- The else statement is not needed in the for loop. Simply returning `word` at the end of the function and returning the correct `string` within the loop is cleaner and computationally faster.
- The code as you wrote it has no catch to make sure `end` appears after `start`. If the `end` character appears after the `start` character, indA will not be defined and you will get an error.

Also, it looks like this code would give you the first instance where s substring begins with the character "start" and ends with the character "end." However, in `str.find(sub, start, end)`, "start" and "end" define a substring of `str` in which to search for `sub`. If you were emulating `str.find()`, you would need four parameters: a string to search from (str), a substring to search for (sub), a starting integer (start) to define where in str to start searching, and an ending integer (end) to define where in str to stop searching.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My break term is added so that the function stops at the first letter that matches the input.

Comment: I have tried  your suggestion of removing the break statements, but now the only return is indA ( line7). Do you have any idea as to why that may be

Comment: I think it was that you needed to remove the return statements as well. I updated my answer to give you a working version of the code.